# Kendo Grid Header and Columns Not Aligned After Grouping

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Before grouping:

[image]

After grouping:

[image]

Code snippet for grid:

```
"controls": [
                {
                    "control_key": "siteassignment_grid",
                    "control_type_key": "grid",
                    "target_device_key": "normal",
                    "configuration": {
                        "AssignmentGrid": {
                            "options": {
                                "AllowSorting": {
                                    "mode": "single",
                                    "allowUnsort": "false"
                                },
                                "AllowFiltering": "true",
                                "AllowGrouping": "true",
                                "AllowReordering": "true",
                                "Selection": "false"
                            },
                            "schema": {
                                "fields": [
                                    "string",
                                    "string",
                                    "string",
                                    "string",
                                    "string",
                                    "string",
                                    "string",
                                    "string",
                                    "string",
                                    "string",
                                    "string",
                                    "string"
                                ]
                            },
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "headerTemplate": "<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' class='chkSelectAll' onclick='SiteAssignment.Widget.SearchSitesAssign.checkAll(this)'/>",
                                    "template": "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' onclick='SiteAssignment.Widget.UpdateAssignment.LoadWidget()'/>", "width": "25px"
                                },
                                {
                                    "field": "element_code",
                                    "title": "Config Item Id",
                                    "min_width": "75",
                                    "max_width": "75",                                                                              
                                },

                                {
                                    "field": "element_desc",
                                    "title": "Config Item Name",
                                    "min_width": "110",
                                    "max_width": "110",
                                    "template": "#= SiteAssignment.Widget.SearchSitesAssign.GridColumnToolTip(element_desc) #"
                                },
```

...etc...

Knowing that the change event is fired when grouping, I checked the code to see if anything there might be causing this. I disabled this and still have the probelm. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible that setting min_width and max_width is causing problems? I'm pretty new to using Kendo UI, but I'm wondering if it recalculates width after grouping or something like that. I would start by hard coding the width values and seeing if it will cooperate more then.